SEOmatic site map image transform failing
We are experiencing this error frequently in logs and have noticed that it's throwing off available resources for other sessions:
2024-08-30 13:48:54 [-][-][-][error][craft\errors\AssetTransformException] craft\errors\AssetTransformException: Failed to generate transform with id of 2. in /www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/AssetTransforms.php:678


Stack trace:
#0  /www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Assets.php(696): craft\services\AssetTransforms->ensureTransformUrlByIndexModel()
#1  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/ImageTransform.php(145): craft\services\Assets->getAssetUrl()
#2  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/services/Helper.php(461): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\ImageTransform::socialTransform()
#3  /www/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php(1570): nystudio107\seomatic\services\Helper->socialTransform()
#4  /www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Template.php(106): twig_get_attribute()
#5  /www/public_html/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/40/4040e96e62995ca628e91a375a9cd26e.php(38): craft\helpers\Template::attribute()
#6  /www/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_196ecf7f2d32119b3b85880a5c9e9b65->doDisplay()
#7  /www/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
#8  /www/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display()
#9  /www/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render()
#10  /www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(623): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render()
#11  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/MetaValue.php(294): craft\web\View->renderObjectTemplate()
#12  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/MetaValue.php(105): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\MetaValue::parseMetaString()
#13  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/MetaValue.php(152): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\MetaValue::parseString()
#14  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/JsonLd.php(120): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\MetaValue::parseArray()
#15  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/JsonLd.php(87): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\JsonLd::normalizeJsonLdArray()
#16  /www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(224): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\JsonLd::processData()
#17  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/JsonLd.php(85): yii\helpers\BaseJson::processData()
#18  /www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(224): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\JsonLd::processData()
#19  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/JsonLd.php(85): yii\helpers\BaseJson::processData()
#20  /www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(224): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\JsonLd::processData()
#21  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/JsonLd.php(85): yii\helpers\BaseJson::processData()
#22  /www/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(75): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\JsonLd::processData()
#23  /www/public_html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Json.php(38): yii\helpers\BaseJson::encode()
#24  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/helpers/JsonLd.php(73): craft\helpers\Json::encode()
#25  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/models/MetaJsonLd.php(258): nystudio107\seomatic\helpers\JsonLd::encode()
#26  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/models/MetaJsonLdContainer.php(163): nystudio107\seomatic\models\MetaJsonLd->render()
#27  /www/public_html/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src/models/MetaJsonLdContainer.php(67): nystudio107\seomatic\models\MMetaJsonLdContainer->renderInternal()
#28 [internal function]: nystudio107\seomatic\models\MetaJsonLdContainer->nystudio107\seomatic\models\{closure}()

The website is in Craft 3 and is very image-heavy.

Would this be solved updating to Craft 4?
How do I turn it off, for now, sacrificing the least of the sitemap and SEO?
How do I fix transforms 1 and 2 to be compatible with this? If it helps.

We discovered this before heading over to Craft 4 - but the impact of this sometimes threatens server resources and updating software is ill-advised on unstable envs. Thanks for your help.

You can try to turn off image transforms for SEOmatic in:
Content -> Choose an entry type -> Sitemap

Also, think about setting some remote image handler, like AWS Sharp.
https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-your-own-image-transform-service

Thank you for your reply. It solves the issue at hand though I fear it could add origination-size images to the sitemap which could create other problems.

Well, unless you can't perform resize operations on the server, you might need to understand how to setup remote image handler or try to figure out what's the problem with the server one.
